# Coding a caching server

Tags: programming-languages, caching, network-programming

I have been researching and have some few ideas about a distributed caching system for a in memory key-value store with replication and all the jazz associated. SO I wanted to know from the community what is the best language/framework/technology mix i should go for.

Comment: Why not use the ones already there?

Comment: Well, memcached might be there but the thing which I am implementing should in theory gives upto 30-40% better performance than memcached for small cache sizes. Hence, an almost from scratch work is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you know there's stuff like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) out there? It's powering some of the busiest sites on the web. No need to reinvent the wheel here.

If you're going write your own anyway, you want to make it as fast as possible, so I'd choose C or C++. Fast, widely supported, easy to write bindings for other languages.

Comment: Well, memcached might be there but the thing which I am implementing should in theory gives upto 30-40% better performance than memcached for small cache sizes.
Thanks for the answer though, I was contemplating between Java and C++ till now mainly because of the the support for distributed systems.